# Is there a way to apply a function on a MultiIndex column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```py
   id sex  isActive  score
0   1   M         1     10
1   2   F         0     20
2   2   F         1     30
3   2   M         0     40
4   3   M         1     50
```

I want to pivot the dataframe on the index `id` and columns `sex` and `isActive` (the value should be `score`). I want each id to have their score be a percentage of their total score associated with the sex group.

In the end, my dataframe should look like this:

```py
sex          F           M      
isActive     0     1     0     1
id                              
1          NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
2          0.4   0.6   1.0   NaN
3          NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0
```

---

I tried pivoting first:

```py
p = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns=['sex', 'isActive'], values='score')
print(p)

sex          F           M      
isActive     0     1     0     1
id                              
1          NaN   NaN   NaN  10.0
2         20.0  30.0  40.0   NaN
3          NaN   NaN   NaN  50.0
```

Then, I summed up the scores for each group:

```py
row_sum = p.sum(axis=1, level=[0])
print(row_sum)

sex     F     M
id             
1     0.0  10.0
2    50.0  40.0
3     0.0  50.0
```

This is where I'm getting stuck. I'm trying to use [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to perform a column-wise sum based on the second dataframe. However, I keep getting errors following this format:

```
p.apply(lambda col: col/row_sum)
```

I may be overthinking this problem. Is there some better approach out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just a simple division of `p` by `row_sum` would work like:

```
print (p/row_sum)
sex         F         M     
isActive    0    1    0    1
id                          
1         NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
2         0.4  0.6  1.0  NaN
3         NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple! Your note is correct, I included the wrong input data. However, your answer still provides me with the correct solution. I've accepted this answer and corrected the input data to reflect your answer. Thank you :)